# Why does this form helper generate two inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On a model, I have `attr_accessor: :email_settings`.

In a view, I have:

```
<%= form_for some_model do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :email_settings do |email_settings| %>
        <%= email_settings.label :general, _("General updates") %>
        <%= email_settings.check_box :general %>
        General site updates
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But in the HTML, this does not create one input for `some_model[email_settings][general]`, it creates two. One hidden and one a checkbox:

```
<label for="user_email_settings_general">General updates</label>
<input name="user[email_settings][general]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="user_email_settings_general" name="user[email_settings][general]" type="checkbox" value="1">
General site updates
```

What's going on here? Why is there a hidden input and a checkbox for the same value, when I only want a checkbox?

Also in the controller action that the form is submitted to, I do this:

```
def update
    puts "email_params: #{email_params}"
end

def email_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email_settings)
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Unpermitted parameters: email_settings
email_params: {}
```

Not sure how `email_settings` is being interpreted as "unpermitted" when I'm explicitly permitting it.

Comment: What is the output of `params.inspect` ?

Comment: I had to change `def email_params` to: `params.require(:user).permit(email_settings: [:general])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the browser should always send a response.
If you do not select the box, will send the hidden field to understand that something has been sent.

In this way the rails will always receive an indication that the box was selected or not.

similar answer is here: [Why does the check_box form helper generate two checkboxes, one hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550941/why-does-the-check-box-form-helper-generate-two-checkboxes-one-hidden)

Comment: But this doesn't work as intended because *two* values are specified instead of one, making `user[email_settings][general]` itself be interpreted as an array of `[0,1]` instead of just `0` or `1`.

Comment: Correction. The above comment of mine is wrong. But there is another issue and I will update the main post.

Comment: email_setings is an array.
Try to put in your model 
`serialize :email_setings, Array`
and your controller `params.require(:user).permit!` to see if it passes