# Rail checkbox with bootstrap buttons

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to use bootstrap buttons(http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) for my checkboxes where users has to select one or many of the options. each check box is a boolean column. But with this code, when i click on the buttons, the check boxes doesn't get selected, neither does the state change.

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">

    <%= f.label :tdm, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :tdm%>
      beginner
    <% end %>


    <%= f.label :Domination, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :casual%>
      casual
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :ctf, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :ctf%>
      competitive
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :demolition, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :demolition%>
      competitive
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

what I'm trying to accomplish 
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12565/

Comment: Are you using simple_form? Check for the html code that your form is creating. You may add the html onto your question if after checking that it's correct and not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is download `bootstrap.min.js` from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and put it in the `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder. Then enable it by adding this line:

`//= require bootstrap.min`

to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file. You can demonstrate that this is part of the problem by going to your jsfiddle and disabling `bootstrap.min.js` under "External Resources".

However, your buttons will probably still not work because Rails automatically generates a hidden `input` when you use the `check_box` function and it breaks the Bootstrap button. You can stop it from creating the hidden `input` with an `include_hidden: false` argument at the end of each of your `check_box` calls.

Now, because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550941/why-does-the-check-box-form-helper-generate-two-checkboxes-one-hidden), I think it's a good idea to put a hidden `input` in your form for each of the ones you disabled. You can just put them somewhere where they won't break the Bootstrap buttons and where they will be overridden by any user input. Anywhere in the form before the first `check_box` `label` should be fine. They should look like this:

```
<%= hidden_field(:your_model_name, :tdm, value: "0") %>
```

That should do it.

*Edited to include replacing hidden inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think your DOM something looks like this

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" for="object_tdm">
    <input name="object[tdm]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="object_tdm" name="object[tdm]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    beginner
  </label>   
</div>
```

In your case when you click on the buttons, the check boxes doesn't get selected, neither does the state change its because of `data-toggle="buttons"`. you remove this attribute and try once. it should work.